# Prepositions and Noun Phrases

Tags: nouns, prepositional-phrases, noun-phrases

does a noun phrase followed by a prepositional phrase form another noun phrase?

Example:

> The road to hell

'The road' and  'hell' form two separate noun phrases.

Does, 'The road to hell'  constitute as a noun phrase in its own right?  if not why?

What about something like,

> The road of power

(i.e: using the preposition 'of' instead of 'to')

Comment: Yes to all your questions. "The road to hell" is an NP, and so is "power". In your last example, "The road of power" is an NP, as is "power".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does [form another noun phrase].

You can tell that easily by using it in a sentence with a main verb:

> *The road to hell* **is** paved with good intentions.

The same can be done with any noun phrase.

> *The road of power* is all in the mind.

Comment: Makes sense thanks!, one more thing would this hold recursively? i.e:  'The road to hell to power'

Comment: Not necessarily. In "You can follow the road to hell to power" *to power* is a prepositional phrase, and *the road to hell* is a noun phrase, the object of *follow*. However, "The road to the hell of power" is: "The road to the hell of power **is** smooth and slippery." But don't get the idea that *to* means that it cannot be a noun phrase and *of* means it must be. Each case needs to be examined, and the easy test in my answer is one (fairly crude) way of doing that.